# How to Allow Window.opener.location.href Permission For Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm using GreaseMonkey in FireFox with the following code

```
if (window.opener) 
{
    alert(window.opener.location.href);
}
```

However, i'm getting a `Permission Denied` error,  possibly due to cross-domain policy. How do i overcome this protection?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do this if the window is on a different domain than its opener.**  For plain javascript, blocking this information is considered a security safeguard.

For Greasemonkey, it *might* be less of a security problem, but the Greasemonkey devs have not added that capability.  Greasemonkey is just plain javascript, with select, limited, extension capabilities added on.

You can [open a feature request](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues) for for this, but it is [unlikely to be approved](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aEnvironment#What.27s_Missing.3F) unless you can make a good case for both: how this is useful, AND how it won't result in careless GM users being "pwned".

---

In the meanwhile, you can always fork [the Greasemonkey source code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey) and build your own version that breaks the cross-domain barrier.

Or, depending on what you are *really* trying to do, there may be a workaround involving two or more script instances communicating.  Open a new question and describe the scenario, *in full detail*, for help with a workaround.

Comment: yes, i can modify greasemonkey and use it. However, i was searching for a ready made answer. Anyways, i'll have to modify greasemonkey for my personal use :(